# Proving the logic problem. would you check please???

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that $A \cup (B \cap C)= (A \cup B ) \cap (A \cup C)$

$x \in A$ or $x \in B$ and $x \in A$ or $x \in C$.

Since $A \cup B$ is $x \in A$ or $x \in B$, $x \in A$ is in $x \in A$ or $x \in B$
Since $A \cup C$ is $x \in A$ or $x \in C$, $x \in A$ is in $x \in A$ or $x \in C$

I would like to learn how to prove better than what i just wrote.

Can you give me a trick or technique to write better? I just started learning logic and I'm having difficulty time with writing mostly.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Your way is essentially fine: By considereing element relations, we reduce this set equality to a logical equivalence:
$$ a\lor(b\land c)\iff (a\lor b)\land(a\lor c).$$
This can be proved by truth tables if one has no better idea. Or by deductions involving standard techniques such as case distinctions etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could also prove using Venn diagrams...